# Google+ id from Google+ App

Tags: google-plus

I would like to get my id profile or my profile URL from the official Google+ app, in order to copy it to clipboard.

- id  : {21-digit-number}
- url : https://plus.google.com/u/0/{21-digit-number}

I would be also interested if there was a way to get it, from any official Google application on Android, different from a browser of course.